# Not able to make url rewrite nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect

I'm trying to create a simple rewrite rule as follow:

```
rewrite ^/ced-course/mobile-app-design-and-development/thank-you/?$ /thanks/ break;
```

but it is not working at all!

I did some research someone suggested to install proxy module to make it work. is it so?

I'm new to Nginx. Anything I'm missing?

I'll appreciate your help

thanks,

-Naveed

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? This rewrite rule won't change the URI in a browser address bar, maybe you want a redirect? Then replace `break` flag with `permanent` one.

Comment: I don't want to redirect. rather I want to map, rather I want to call page
/thanks/
to 
/ced-course/mobile-app-design-and-development/thank-you/
so content will be from /thanks/
url will be /ced-course/mobile-app-design-and-development/thank-you/

Comment: That depends on your backend architecture. What is your backend?